# PHP: Format each table column with specific function

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I want to print HTML table (30+ cols, 500+ rows) but before that I have to apply different function on almost each column values.

```
$sampleData = array(
    0 => array(
        'date' => '2015-10-20',
        'time' => '12:30:00',
        'price' => 500,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'date' => '2015-10-21',
        'time' => '08:10:00',
        'price' => 250,
        'currency' => 'USD'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'date' => '2015-10-22',
        'time' => '21:45:00',
        'price' => 300,
        'currency' => 'EUR'
    )
);
```

So far I solved it with array of columns and names of functions that are called with `call_user_func`.

```
$cols = array(
    'date' => 'self::formatDate',
    'time' => 'self::formatTime'
);
```

And then create table like this:

```
$htmlRows = '';
foreach ($sampleData as $row) {
    $htmlRows .= '<tr>';

    foreach ($cols as $th => $function) {
        $htmlRows .= '<td>'.call_user_func($cols[$th], $row[$th]).'</td>';
    }

    $htmlRows .= '</tr>';
}
```

To me it looked like quite elegant solution, but than I stuck on how to call function with two or more params, e.g. `formatPrice($price, $currency);` on third column while its values are stored under third and fourth key. Or is there a better way how to format table columns?

Thanks, sorry for english

Comment: [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) documentation states _Calls the callback given by the first parameter and passes the remaining parameters as arguments._, so you could pass the currency as a third argument to call_user_func(). But in your case, the currency comes from a different database field, which contradicts your paradigma of 'formatting each (single) table column with a specific function'.

Comment: Almost each, therefore I have list of columns `$cols` I want to print extended with name of particular function. Next `$cols` key in this example will be 'price' but not 'currency'.

Comment: So maybe incorporate all fields you want to use for a specific column in a way you could split them easily, `foreach` over them and pass the collected values to `call_user_func()` as an array? Like `'price,currency' => 'self::formatPrice'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition:

Incorporate all fields you want to use for a specific column in a way you can split them easily, iterate over them and pass the collected values.

```
$cols = array(
    'date' => 'self::formatDate',
    'time' => 'self::formatTime',
    'price,currency' => 'self::formatPrice',
);
```

and

```
$htmlRows = '';
foreach ($sampleData as $row) {
    $htmlRows .= '<tr>';

    foreach ($cols as $group => $function) {
        $data = array();
        $fields = explode(',', $group);
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $data[$field] = $row[$field];
        }
        $htmlRows .= '<td>'.call_user_func($cols[$th], $data).'</td>';
    }

    $htmlRows .= '</tr>';
}
```

You will have to adapt your `formatXxx()` functions to interpret the different representation.

It is actually a good idea to use the actual class name instead of `self` in the $cols array, because if you declare the functions as private and extend the class, the functions will not be found.

Comment: It should be `call_user_func_array` in this case but I get the idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you you use call_user_func_array(), you get only the values, but not the association. Referring to `$data['price']` and `$data['currency']` is in my opinion the more stable solution in this case. But yes, if you use call_user_func_array(), you won't have to change anything in your existing formatting functions.

Comment: But array of parameters (`data`) can be only passed to `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: The difference between the two is that call_user_func_array() takes the arguments from the array (and allows for only two parameters), where call_user_func() takes an abritrary long list of parameters of `mixed` type (which would include arrays and objects). Possibly the documentation is incomplete here, I did not run that code.

Comment: I did and in this case only call_user_func_array works as expected :) Anyway thanks, this solution is great.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to do another `foreach` and prepare a second array that is used for the HTML formatting.

```
foreach ($sampleData as $row) {
    $newSampleData['date'] = self::formatDate($row['date']);
    $newSampleData['something'] = self::formatDate($row['something'],'argument1','argument2');
    ... and so on
```

Then you use `$newSampleData` for your HTML code.

Comment: This is where I started of course, but than I tried to edit my code to look more pro :)